# React - Material UI Drawer and Header Bar

Tags: reactjs

This is my first post, so let me know if I have done anything wrong. I have searched for an answer, and have not been able to find anything on this site or anywhere else. I have started playing around with React to make an intranet application at work. My previous knowledge is mostly .Net and I was only an amateur at that.

For my application I am leveraging the NPM Material UI modules. I am trying to get the Drawer to always be below the header bar and the header bar to move all the way across the screen. Currently, the position of the drawer blocks out part of the header part. My current App.js is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import { mainListItems, secondaryListItems } from './Components/Sidebar.js';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  chevronLeft: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  chevronRight: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  chevronRightButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 36,
  },

  chevronRightButtonHidden: {
    display: 'none',
  },

  chevronLeftButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 36,
  },

  chevronLeftButtonHidden: {
    display: 'none',    
  },

  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: 'relative',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 7,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9,
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    height: '100vh',
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
  chartContainer: {
    marginLeft: -22,
  },
  tableContainer: {
    height: 320,
  },
});

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: true,
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <AppBar
            position="absolute"
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, this.state.open && classes.appBarShift)}
          >
            <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open} className={classes.toolbar}>
              <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.title}>
                Dashboard
              </Typography>
              <IconButton color="inherit">
                <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                  <NotificationsIcon />
                </Badge>
              </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>

          <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            classes={{
              paper: classNames(classes.drawerPaper, !this.state.open && classes.drawerPaperClose),}}
            open={this.state.open}
          >

            <Divider />
            <List>{mainListItems}</List>
            <Divider />
            <List>{secondaryListItems}</List>
            <div className={classes.chevronLeft}>
              <IconButton 
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Close drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}
                // className={classNames(
                //   classes.chevronLeftButton,
                //   this.state.open && classes.chevronLeftButtonHidden,)}
              >
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>

            <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="Open drawer"
                onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
                className={classNames(
                  classes.chevronRightButton,
                  this.state.open && classes.chevronRightButtonHidden,)}
              >
                <ChevronRightIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Drawer>

        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Dashboard);
```

You will no doubt notice the Chevrons don't work correctly. Only one is supposed to be visible at a time, but I am still working on that.

Any advice you can give me to correct the appearance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Mitch

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to obtain but if you don't apply the `appBarShift` class in the `AppBar` component when the drawer is opened then the header nav wont move.

Comment: Thanks. I after I wrote this, I figured out how to push down the side bar by adding a `height` to the drawpaper, but what you described was immediately my next problem. So thanks!!!